# Running node script from Laravel http request causes node::http2::Http2Session::OnStreamAllocImpl error

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

This is a strange error that works in certain cases, but not in others. I'm trying to run a node script that requires a bit of memory. Running it directly in the command line works fine.

```
> node data-processor.js my-argument # outputs my-test-string
```

No problems here. Running it like this through an Artisan command works fine:

```
// MyCommand.php
public function handle()
{
     $output = shell_exec(base_path('data-processor.js my-argument'));
     // $output = 'my-test-string'
}
```

However, running this in a controller from an HTTP request causes the following error:

```
// MyController.php
public function myControllerMethod()
{
     $output = shell_exec(base_path('data-processor.js my-argument'));
     // $output is null
}
```

Appending `2>&1` to the call gives me the following:

```
$output = exec(base_path('data-processor.js my-argument 2>&1'));

node[8584]: ../src/node_http2.cc:1934:static void node::http2::Http2Session::OnStreamAllocImpl(size_t, uv_buf_t*, void*): Assertion `(session->stream_buf_.base) == (nullptr)' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8cd87b [node]
 3: node::http2::Http2Session::OnStreamAllocImpl(unsigned long, uv_buf_t*, void*) [node]
 4: node::TLSWrap::ClearOut() [node]
 5: node::TLSWrap::OnReadImpl(long, uv_buf_t const*, uv_handle_type, void*) [node]
 6: node::LibuvStreamWrap::OnRead(uv_stream_s*, long, uv_buf_t const*) [node]
 7: 0x9c589f [node]
 8: 0x9c5ed0 [node]
 9: 0x9cb580 [node]
10: uv_run [node]
11: node::Start(uv_loop_s*, int, char const* const*, int, char const* const*) [node]
12: node::Start(int, char**) [node]
13: __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
14: 0x89f601 [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

An important note is that if the dataset is small, this works fine. Larger datasets cause this error. These datasets are not really all that big. They produce JSON files up to 20mb max. That data is not uploaded directly from the HTTP request, but triggered to retrieve it from Google Cloud Firestore once that route is hit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: Node version is v12.17.0. I tried downgrading to v10 but I got the same error.